# Windows C++ UWP: wait XX milliseconds until event occurs

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::
    MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->
    ProcessEvents(Windows::UI::Core::CoreProcessEventsOption::
                  ProcessOneAndAllPending);
```

However with a timeout in milliseconds, ex: wait up to 50 ms until an event occurs.

In Win32 I can do:

```
MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, null, false, wait, 
                          QS_ALLINPUT);
```

But can't do that for UWP.

Alternatively, is there any way to know if there are any events waiting?
So I could do a combination of checking if events are present combined with `Sleep(1)`

Comment: Create a timer that posts an event to your dispatcher after 50ms. If you want to poll, then use ProcessOneIfPresent or ProcessAllIfPresent.

Comment: how to create a timer? I've tried doing "Timer=ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer();" and I'm getting an exception "HRESULT:0x8001010E The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."

Comment: Then I've tried creating it inside RunAsync: if(!Timer)
   Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([=]()
            {
               if(!Timer)
               {
                  Timer=ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer();
               }
            }));
and same crash again

Comment: Use a plain timer, not a dispatcher timer. The plain timer posts an event to the dispatcher; it doesn't need to run on the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Task.Run(async () => { await YourMethod(); }).Wait(5);
```

I use this method in C#. But am not sure about C++.